# Как кликнуть на элемент через Javascript?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть `select option`

```
<select class="equipment_type" id="equipment_type">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="659">Иванов Иван</option>
</select>
```

И на странице также есть обработчик события.

```
$('select.equipment_type').live(($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change'),
            function()
            {

                var equipment_type = $(this).val();

                var html = $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/request-invoice.php?request_type=' + request_type + '&action=get_equipment&equipment_type=' + equipment_type + '&request_id=' + request_id,
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
                $(this).next().remove();
                $(this).after(html);
            }
        );
```

Я пытаюсь теперь выбрать элемент и чтобы сработало событие `click`

```
var select = document.querySelector('#equipment_type');
select.value = 659;
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Значение выбирается корректно, но событие не генерится. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: в каком браузере пробуешь?

Comment: хромиум.........

Comment: ага, а событие ты какое вешаешь? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде присутствуют `.live()` и `$.browser`, а это значит, что используется библиотека *JQuery* версии менее 1.9.0 или более новая версия с подключенным плагином [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). Это создаёт некоторые нюансы.

---

При назначении обработчика, условие выбирает событие `change`, т.к. из комментариев понятно, что просматриваете в *Chromium*. Но, пытаетесь инициировать событие `click`, которое не отслеживается в силу условия и используемого браузера.

Логично посылать событие `change`. К тому же, устаревшая версия библиотеки требует указания дополнительного параметра в конструкторе событий `new Event()`, такого как *bubbles (всплытие)* :

```js
$('select.equipment_type').live(($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change'), function(ev) {
  var equipment_type = $(this).val();
  
  console.log('Сработало событие', ev.type);
  
  var html = $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/request-invoice.php?request_type=' + request_type + '&action=get_equipment&equipment_type=' + equipment_type + '&request_id=' + request_id,
    async: false
  }).responseText;
  $(this).next().remove();
  $(this).after(html);
});

var select = document.querySelector('#equipment_type');
select.value = 659;
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="equipment_type" id="equipment_type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="659">Иванов Иван</option>
</select>
```

---

Если используете *jQuery*, то будет правильнее задействовать возможности актуальных версий этой библиотеки и не мешать, без особой необходимости, с нативным *JavaScript*-кодом:

```js
$('select.equipment_type').on('click change', function(ev) {
  var equipment_type = $(this).val();
  
  console.log('Сработало событие', ev.type);
  
  var html = $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/request-invoice.php?request_type=' + request_type + '&action=get_equipment&equipment_type=' + equipment_type + '&request_id=' + request_id,
    async: false
  }).responseText;
  $(this).next().remove();
  $(this).after(html);
});

$('#equipment_type').val('659').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="equipment_type" id="equipment_type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="659">Иванов Иван</option>
</select>
```